# Plone: collective.transmogrifier.sections.constructor doesn't write objects while importing

Tags: plone, data-migration, plone-4.x, transmogrifier

I'm almost successful in my efforts to transfer an excerpt of my ZODB (a small subset of folders, including resources taken from other folders) to another Plone instance; the showstopper is: during import, my objects are not written.
Here is my export script:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    sitewalker
    xmlwalker
    uidextractor
    encapsulator
    manifestexporter
    fileexporter
    marshaller
    propertiesexporter
    commentsexporter
    datacorrector
    portletsexporter
    writer
    EXPORTING

[sitewalker]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.sitewalker
path =
    folder1
    folder2

[xmlwalker]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.xmlwalker

[uidextractor]
# my own section which parses the html text of the given fields,
# checks the href and src attributes for UIDs, and injects entries
# for the refered objects into the pipeline
blueprint = my.transmogrifier.uidextractor
inspect_fields =
    text
    description
    notes

[encapsulator]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.mimeencapsulator
mimetype = item/_mimetype
field = string:datafield

[manifestexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.manifestexporter

[fileexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.fileexporter

[marshaller]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.marshaller

[propertiesexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertiesexporter

[commentsexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.commentsexporter

[datacorrector]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.datacorrector
sources =
    marshall

[portletsexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.portletsexporter

[writer]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer
context = directory
path = var/export/
prefix = structure

[EXPORTING]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger
keys =
    _type
    _path
```

Based on the default export and import scripts from `quintagroup.transmogrifier`, here is my import script:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    reader
    pathfixer
    constructor
    schemaupdater
    datacorrector
    demarshaller
    uidupdater
    referencesimporter
    propertiesimporter
    commentsimporter
    portletsimporter
    printcounters
    IMPORTING

[reader]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.reader
prefix = 
path = /path/to/var/export
context = directory
# unchanged entries I don't really understand:
.objects.xml = manifest
.marshall.xml = marshall
.properties.xml = propertymanager
.comments.xml = comments
.file-fields.xml = file-fields
.interfaces.xml = interfaces
.portlets.xml = portlets

[pathfixer]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.pathfixer
stripstring = Plone/
prependstring = 

[constructor]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.constructor

[schemaupdater]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.atschemaupdater

[datacorrector]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.datacorrector
type = import
sources =
    marshall

[fileimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.fileimporter

[demarshaller]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.demarshaller

[uidupdater]
blueprint = plone.app.transmogrifier.uidupdater

[referencesimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.referencesimporter

[propertiesimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertiesimporter

[commentsimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.commentsimporter

[portletsimporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.portletsimporter

[printcounters]
blueprint = collective.transmogrifier.sections.summary
count = true

[IMPORTING]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger
keys = 
    _type
    _path
```

As far as I understand, the `reader` comes up to the `writer`;
the `marshaller` comes up for the `demarshaller`, etc.
However, while importing, the objects are not actually written to the
database.  Tweaking the blueprints with a counting facility (in the
`add-info` branch of my forks of the packages), I got the following
overview:

```
Items summary
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[reader]:
  created:   714
[pathfixer]:
  got:         714
  forwarded:   714
  stripped:    390
[constructor]:
  got:            714
  missing-type:   714
  missing-info:   714
  forwarded:      714
[datacorrector]:
  got:         714
  forwarded:   714
[fileimporter]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[demarshaller]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[uidupdater]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[referencesimporter]:
  passed-through:    31
[printcounters]:
  passed-through:    31
[IMPORTING]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
```

When the `constructor` doesn't do anything about the `item`, I count the reasons;  obviously the `constructor` section doesn't write anything because it doesn't know the types of the objects to create.  But shouldn't this
information have been created somewhere?!

(There is another problem: apparently the `fileimporter` receives only
31 objects of the 714 passed on by the `datacorrector`.  But first I'd
like to see anything imported.)

What am I doing wrong?

Oh, and online documentation for the `collective.transmogrifier.sections` would be nice;they even lack docstrings ...

**Edit**: My counting-enabled forks are here (branches `add-info`):

- [collective.transmogrifier](https://github.com/tobiasherp/collective.transmogrifier)
- [plone.app.transmogrifier](https://github.com/tobiasherp/plone.app.transmogrifier)
- [quintagroup.transmogrifier](https://github.com/tobiasherp/quintagroup.transmogrifier)

**2nd Edit**:

When I move the `IMPORTING` section before `constructer`, the counters output is:

```
Items summary
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[reader]:
  created:   714
[pathfixer]:
  got:         714
  forwarded:   714
  stripped:    390
[IMPORTING]:
  got:         714
  forwarded:   714
[constructor]:
  got:            714
  missing-type:   714
  missing-info:   714
  forwarded:      714
[datacorrector]:
  got:         714
  forwarded:   714
[fileimporter]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[demarshaller]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[uidupdater]:
  got:          31
  forwarded:    31
[referencesimporter]:
  passed-through:    31
[printcounters]:
  passed-through:    31
```

Thus, the `collector` still can't find `_type` information.

**3rd Edit:**

I added a little facility which prints a short info about the items found (the 1st item per section by default; `_path` and `_type` with values, if present, and a list of the other keys).  The result is:

```
[reader], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #2:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
2015-08-18 18:39:56 INFO IMPORTING _path=
[constructor], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[reader], item #2:
    _path='some/archetypes/object/containing/a/video'
    other keys: _files (dict), _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
```

Indeed there are no `_type` keys anywhere, so I need a section which provides them.

**4th Edit:**

After re-inserting `manifestimporter` before `constructor`, I got:

```
[reader], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #2:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
2015-08-19 10:15:43 INFO IMPORTING _path=
[constructor], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[manifestimporter], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[reader], item #2:
    _path='    [reader], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[pathfixer], item #2:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
2015-08-19 10:15:43 INFO IMPORTING _path=
[constructor], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[manifestimporter], item #1:
    _path=''
    other keys: _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
[reader], item #2:
    _path='some/archetypes/object/containing/a/video'
    other keys: _files (dict), _import_context (DirectoryImportContext)
...
2015-08-19 10:15:44 INFO IMPORTING
Pipeline processing time: 00:00:00
         715 items were generated in source sections
           2 went through full pipeline
         713 were discarded in some section
```

The `manifestimporter` sections doesn't forward any previous items, so all items from `reader` are thrown away.

**5th Edit:**
Tried the [recommended way](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.transmogrifier/plone3-4) to use the "Site Configuration Export Step;" I edited the default export script and tried the export, but I got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 598, in manage_exportSelectedSteps
  Module Products.GenericSetup.tool, line 1053, in _doRunExportSteps
  Module quintagroup.transmogrifier.exportimport, line 74, in exportSiteStructure
  Module collective.transmogrifier.utils, line 121, in constructPipeline
  Module quintagroup.transmogrifier.sitewalker, line 29, in __init__
TypeError: ('Could not adapt', {'manifestexporter': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.manifestexporter'}, 'transmogrifier': {'pipeline': '\nsitewalker\nuidextractor\npathfixer\nmanifestexporter\nfileexporter\nmarshaller\npropertiesexporter\ncommentsexporter\ndatacorrector\nportletsexporter\nwriter\nEXPORTING'}, 'uidextractor': {'blueprint': 'my.transmogrifier.uidextractor', 'trace-first': 'true', 'inspect_fields': '\ntext\ndescription\nnotes'}, 'sitewalker': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.sitewalker', 'start-path': '\nakademie/vortraege/d-02-verlegung-lektion-02-leitungsgraben', 'exclude-contained': 'false'}, 'xmlwalker': {'blueprint': 'collective.transmogrifier.sections.xmlwalker'}, 'encapsulator': {'blueprint': 'plone.app.transmogrifier.mimeencapsulator', 'mimetype': 'item/_mimetype', 'field': 'string:datafield'}, 'writer': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer', 'path': 'var/export/', 'prefix': '', 'context': 'tarball'}, 'commentsexporter': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.commentsexporter'}, 'pathfixer': {'blueprint': 'plone.app.transmogrifier.pathfixer', 'stripstring': 'unitracc/'}, 'echo': {'blueprint': 'visaplan.transmogrifier.echo'}, 'marshaller': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.marshaller'}, 'propertiesexporter': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertiesexporter'}, 'datacorrector': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.datacorrector', 'sources': '\nmarshall'}, 'breakpoint': {'blueprint': 'collective.transmogrifier.sections.breakpoint'}, 'EXPORTING': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger', 'keys': '\n_type\n_path'}, 'portletsexporter': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.portletsexporter'}, 'fileexporter': {'blueprint': 'quintagroup.transmogrifier.fileexporter'}}, <InterfaceClass zope.annotation.interfaces.IAnnotations>)
```

It didn't matter whether or not my `uidexporter` section was included.

**6th Edit:**

Here is the current export profile which I used for the Site Configuration Export Step:

```
[transmogrifier]
pipeline =
    sitewalker
    manifestexporter
    fileexporter
    marshaller
    propertiesexporter
    commentsexporter
    datacorrector
    portletsexporter
    writer
    EXPORTING

[sitewalker]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.sitewalker
exclude-contained = false
start-path =
    Plone/some/existing/structure

[manifestexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.manifestexporter

[fileexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.fileexporter

[marshaller]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.marshaller

[propertiesexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.propertiesexporter

[commentsexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.commentsexporter

[datacorrector]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.datacorrector
sources =
    marshall

[portletsexporter]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.portletsexporter

[writer]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.writer
context = tarball
path = var/export/
prefix =

[EXPORTING]
blueprint = quintagroup.transmogrifier.logger
keys =
    _type
    _path
```

**7th Edit:**
A short information which kind of data is required by the `reader` to enable the `constructor` to create objects, and which section of the export pipeline (with an idea about the necessary options) might earn easy 150 reputation points ;-)

Comment: The [constructor blueprint](https://github.com/tobiasherp/collective.transmogrifier/blob/master/docs/source/sections/constructor.rst) needs the '_type' key or similar to work out which type to create & the _path key to work out where to put it.  Move the IMPORTING section before the constructor section in the pipeline & tell us what gets printed.

Comment: @Danimal: You are right, there is a `rst` page for most of the blueprints. I edited my question and added some information.

Comment: can you pastie your export pipeline please?

Comment: What is the visaplan.transmogrifier.echo in your traceback? It's not in your pipeline :-/ Maybe you need to restart (or rerun buildout)?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. It doesn't do anything special; it just prints the items and yields them, similar to other blueprints I found later.

Comment: Try using pdb In sitewalker?

Comment: I think you would do better just trying to prove q.tm is broken in a vanilla Plone install. If so - raise a bug against in github, if not then build from there.

Comment: If the same goal could be achieved e.g. with `plone.app.transmogrifier` blueprints, this would be fine with me. Sadly I couldn't find useful hints about (pretty standard, I'd say) working export and corresponding import pipelines.  Oh, and I don't insist in using the "Site configuration export" method.

Comment: Yep, I vaguely remember similar difficulties finding out how to get starting the Transmogrifier. I mentioned the common use stories as I saw it [in my blog](http://www.jowettenterprises.com/blog/plone-content-migration-using-transmogrifier-and-collective.jsonify) - but you've already read that, but basically I think most people do use quintagroup.transmogrifier to export / import, so it *should* work.  In conclusion: you are on a mainstream track with q.tm - so try to prove it broken or otherwise

Comment: @Danimal: I issued [an error](https://github.com/collective/quintagroup.transmogrifier/issues/11) for default export script which is IMHO definitely broken.

Comment: Ok, hopefully that gets a response.  Add a foolproof way to prove the error would improve your chances.

Answer (score 0):

From a comparison to [quintagroup.transmogrifier's import.cfg](https://github.com/collective/quintagroup.transmogrifier/blob/master/quintagroup/transmogrifier/import.cfg) You are missing a manifestimporter section in your pipeline.  Their pipeline reads:

```
pipeline =
    reader
    manifestimporter
    constructor
    datacorrector
    fileimporter
    demarshaller
    referencesimporter
    propertiesimporter
    commentsimporter
    portletsimporter
    IMPORTING
```

Comment: True. I had commented out this one because the `manifestimporter` doesn't forward any of the previous items, and because I could not find any documentation about it. See my update.

Comment: Ok, but you seem to be far off the beaten track here.  Can you not try following one of the How to's at the bottom of [this page](http://projects.quintagroup.com/products/wiki/quintagroup.transmogrifier) and report back?  "Content migration from Plone 3 to Plone 4" will probably suit you even if you are doing 4 to 4...

Comment: Yes, sorry; urgent things to do meanwhile. Tried the Site configuration Export, but no success; traceback following.

Comment: updated the question, including a traceback. I'm not sure the site configuration export step works currently, but this might depend on the versions involved ...